# Check if variable is good for jQuery each

Tags: jquery

I personally love $.each function - it allows working with arrays and objects in simple and equal way. But somtimes when some part of application passes non-object to that function I get runtime error 'can't get property length of undefined'.

Such error is really diffucult to debug because it's not known which on of $.each functions caused it. So what I think - it's easier for me to make object check before every $.each call.

How do I check if object suits $.each function? May be there is a way to extend jquery function - to at least know what was sent to $.each? Becuse overwise searching for runtime error is quite difficult - I have 370+ usages of $.each in code ...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
var obj = {1: [{}, {}], 2: []};
$.each(obj, function(key, value){
     $.each(value, function(index, el){
    //fails with 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'
    })

})
```

Comment: `if (variableName && variableName.length) { $.each(...); }`? Though, for a better, more-useful, answer you need to show us some code, ideally code that reproduces the failures.

Comment: Check with if/else statement and then pass variable to $.each. To check if variable is object u can use `typeof(var)` and `var instanceof something`. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can probably overwrite the method for debug purposes or make a custom one. Found an example [here.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-ask-ben-overriding-core-jquery-methods.htm).

Comment: I do can make a check BEFORE fuction starts. 370 times all over the project. But may be there is more effective wat?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put your existing code in a try catch and use proper error handling?

Comment: try catch is an evil. it's good for user, but not for developer - because you'll know what function caused an error but you'll not know inn what exact part of functoin. So for production code I envelope all functions to try-catch automatically, but not for development ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a simple function which checks for whether an object is an object or array or not.

```
function isObjectValidForEach(obj) {
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]' ||  Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var a = [];
isObjectValidForEach(a);
//true
var b = {};
isObjectValidForEach(b);
//true
var c = "hjgfkjwe";
isObjectValidForEach(c);
//false
```

Your code will then change to

```
var obj = {1: [{}, {}], 2: []};

if(isObjectValidForEach(obj)) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
       if(isObjectValidForEach(value)) {
            $.each(value, function(index, el){
                 // your code
            });
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll extend jquery with your code, so I wold at least know where that happened by consoling arguments.callee.caller.toString()